# Spring Security URL authentication and authorization issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Actually If any user using any URL without a prior login, Application should redirect to login page, Once user is login and want to access admin related link it should deny for admin if loggedin user does not belong to admin group.

I am using below code

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_READER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" /
```

but when user who belong to ROLE_READER role is also able to access admin link.
I tried my hard but not able to get rid of this issue.
It will great if someone can provide any pointer.

Comment: You have the list in the wrong order. Place the "/**" pattern last. The patterns are evaluated in order and the first match is used.

Comment: @LukeTaylor you are great. I spent more then 1hours. Thanks. I am ready accept it as answer as its working fine after putting the same in last.

Comment: Glad you got it working :).